# Django is rendering without context. Why?

Tags: python, django, scope, rendering

I am building a new framework for an institution. I'm currently working with Django to create the framework. When i was creating the "New user" form, i noticed that some parts of the page was rendering without context. Why is that?

Look:

**view.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def index(request):
    context = {
               'user': request.user,
               'userDB': User.objects.all()
              }
    return render(request, 'user/home.html', context)

def new_user(request):
    return render(request, 'users/new.html', {})
```

**user/home.html**

```
{% user.username %}
```

**user/new.html**

```
{% user.username %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),                                        # User homepage
    url(r'^new/', views.new_user),                                  # Add user
    url(r'^(?P<user>[0-9]+)/edit', views.edit_user),            # Edit user
]
```

As you can see, there is no context available to render **new_user**, but it renders it. I am afraid this could bring some problems in the future. Although, it's the desired effect, but i don't understand it...

Comment: Show your urls.py

Comment: Urls updated!!!

Comment: do you have `edit_user` view? If yes, post it

Comment: No, i don't. My point is: in `index` view, the context is working properly. But in the `new_user` view, is assuming the `index` context, i think, because is working... I just don't understand it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that `user` instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.User` is **always** passed to the context for you by Django. It's just the same as `request.user`. Even if `User` isn't registered or logged in an instance of `AnonymousUser` will be passed.

Comment: So, if i put `{% user.username %}` in the template, it will render `User` instance without any context?

Comment: @MarcoAurélio yes. Also it's a good practice to check weather user is authenticated using `user.is_authenticated` so then you can decide weather to show their username or not

Comment: I didn't know that... Is that in the documentation?`

Comment: @MarcoAurélio, I'd reccomend you to start with [docs on django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/)